# Change div color on checkbox selection

Tags: php, html, css

I have got three div blocks with three checkboxes and I would like to change the div blocks background color when I click on each checkbox.

When I try this:

```
<style type="text/css">

.calendar-content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 112px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}


.checkbox:checked ~ .calendar-content {
  background: #CCC;
}
</style>



<div class="calendar-content checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_campaign" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 28px; float: left;">
</div>

<div class="calendar-content checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_campaign" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 28px; float: left;">
</div>

<div class="calendar-content checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_campaign" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 28px; float: left;">
</div>
```

It will not change the color for each div block when I click on each checkbox. I dont know why it wont let me to change the div blocks color so I guess there is something wrong with my code.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sx5p4j3k/

Can you please show me an example how I could use css to change the color for the div blocks when I click on each checkbox?

Thank you.

Comment: the duplicate deal with hover but you can easily used checked instead or at least you will get some idea of workarounds

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your advice, do you know what I should use with checked to change the color for the div? I have tried to use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .calendar-content {
  background: #CCC;
}` but it wont change the color. Any idea?

Comment: I have also tried `.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
  background: #CCC;
}`, it still dont do anything.

Comment: there is no way to target a parent element, you need to check the duplicates in order to find some workarounds. Basically what you want to do isn't possible with direct CSS, you need to hack it.

Comment: Well I have try it to hack it but it didn't work. I have looking into google and it say that css will work. I tried it but it still didn't work. What I am not happy is you havent been helping me to resolve it.